# How to call an Ajax view from template?

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

I have some views that are loaded via Ajax calls. But when rendering the initial page, the one that makes the Ajax calls, I may want from beginning to have one of my Ajax views loaded right away.

I.e., in my template I have something like:

```
{% if something_happen %}
<p>Some text.</p>
{% else %}
{# Render my ajax view here #}
{% endif %}
```

I could either replace `{# Render my ajax view here #}` with some Javascript that will make the actual Ajax request, or I could do some trick at Django side, calling and rendering the view right away, saving one round-trip over the network.

I don't like the first option for performance reasons, and the second one seems messy.

The cleanest way I thought of implementing this server side trick was to have some way to call and inline the Ajax view from inside the template. The second best way is to take the HttpResponse returned from the Ajax view, and in some way embed its content in the template. Other options includes repeating myself, and I must not repeat myself.

What is the best way to embed an Ajax view from start? Is there a template tag that calls an inlines a view? If not, how can I write one? Is that a good idea? How to proceed?

Comment: Please share the code for the initial and ajax view controllers.

Comment: What do you mean? For the ajax part, the code is the same.

Comment: Django has views (functional and class based) that a URL maps to. If you can share the view code that you are using for the initial view and also the code for the ajax view I'll be able to craft an answer. The answer could be different depending on what you are doing in these views.

Comment: I don't have the code here right now, but I basically have 2 ajax views with a different form in each (they may accept POST or GET requests, like the way forms are used in Django docs). I may need to use one, other or neither from start. And now that you made me think of it, it may be enough just to instantiate the empty form in the non-ajax view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a template that implements a view that might normally be called from Ajax, you could load that server-side with the following:

```
{% include 'my_template.html' %}
```

That is assuming that any variables you'd normally populate in the Ajax view are already present in the context you're including the template. If you needed to add context, you could do:

```
{% with local_var as template_var %}
    {% include 'my_template.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: They are not, and that is the problem. For the variables, I either need to call the view, or to duplicate the code, or refactor everything to have the view's logic in a separated function and have one hell of a mess.

Comment: OK... but if that's too much effort at this point, it's hard to see what part of the server-side solution would be cleaner. I'd leave it as a browser-side Ajax insert until/unless it's worth the effort to refactor.